Inclusion of L1 into the dual of L^infty
As the title suggests I want to find an inclusion of $L^1$ into $(L^\infty)^*$.
I was thinking of just picking
$\lambda_f(g)=\int fg$ and then arguing that I cannot construct a delta functional at some point in this manner, ie $\delta_{x_0}(g)=g(x_0)$
I am doubting myself a little on this so does this actually work or should I think of something else?

Why don't you use MathJax on the title too?
